# One more question about scripting

Tags: bitcoin-core, script

1. Is it possible to write a script that would allow withdrawal of money only to a specific address?
2. Is it possible to write a script that would allow withdrawal only specific amount?

Any examples ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin script has no way to get information about the outputs of a transaction spending it, so no, neither of those things are possible. If you want withdrawal only to a specific address, why not just send to that address the desired amount in the first place and save yourself a transaction fee?